# How to suppress these “Application needs installed” notifications from Google Maps?

Tags: notifications, google-maps, google, google-play-services

Since the last Google Maps update, it periodically shows an “Application needs installed: Request of install from Google Maps” airpush notification begging me to install Google Play services.

I do not want it installed, since i do not have enough disk space on my phone, and Maps seem to function normally (aside from the usual graphics glitches) without Play Services installed. I do not use other Google apps aside from Maps.

How to get rid of these notifications?

If relevant, i am using Android 4.1.2 (Cyanogenmod unofficial) on Sony Arc S.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I recommend you do is, if you're on Android 5.0 or up, there is a simple to use notification manager, where you can block apps notifications. Go in and block the Maps, then enjoy.

Otherwise, I will recommend you forget using Maps app on your phone, and use the Maps in the browser instead (Chrome is your best bet). Since maps is the only Google app you use on your phone, it definitely wouldn't make sense to grab play services, aside your not enough disk space issue. So go ahead and enjoy the Maps app in the browser. It works flawlessly too, and might give you better results and speed compared to a Maps app running without Play services.

Comment: -1 but only because of a factual error. I am using Android 4.1 **but** there is indeed an option to disable notifications from individual apps! Will upvote if you correct your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also: Can’t install Chrome because not enough space! Also need Maps app for navigation.

Comment: Don't you think it would have been best on your part to mention you need the app for Navigation in your actual question? And if there's option to disable notifications from individual apps, what have you done, and did it work or not? You leave holes in your question, and one's who try to help, you vote them down, really? Where did I make the factual error?

Comment: I found that [option](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/how-to-disable-annoying-android-notifications/) only because you mentioned it. Yes, it did help.

Comment: @kinokijuf What option did you find? I'm confused.

Comment: To mute notifications from a specific app. See link.

Answer (score 0):

The only way possible is to root your phone and install Xposed Framework.
It has a module, [This App Will Run Without Google Play Services](http://repo.xposed.info/module/xeed.xposed.dngmod), which makes Play Services installation not compulsory for certain apps (including Maps); it's compatible with Android 2.3 – 5.0.